# how to validate input field which has name in array type using jquery.validate.min.js

Tags: jquery, input, jquery-validate

I have `input` tag fields which has `name` attribute in `array` 
**for i.e.**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
        <span style="color: red;">*</span>
        Title</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8 general-title tooltip-demo">

<input type="text" name="form[1][title]" id="title" value="" size="64" class="form-control" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="" required="required" data-original-title="Enter Notification Title">    </div>
</div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
        <span style="color: red;">*</span>
        Title 2</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8 general-title tooltip-demo">

<input type="text" name="form[2][title]" id="title" value="" size="64" class="form-control" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="" required="required" data-original-title="Enter Notification Title">    </div>
</div>
```

I know, i can do validation like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#frmforgot").validate({
        rules: {
            form[1][title]: {
                required: true
            },
            form[2][title]: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

But i don't want to separate each validation rule, because i have 30 different fields so i don't want to write `30 * 2` rules.

If anyone know easy way, please suggest me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [the `.rules()` method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) to assign any rules to the fields in bulk.

It's this simple...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#frmforgot").validate();

    $('input[name^="form"]').each(function() {
        $(this).rules('add', {
            required: true
        });
    });

});
```

In your case, it does not matter that the naming is using array format.  The `input[name^="form"]` selector is looking for any `input` with a `name` starting with the letters `form`.

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/3e9d4v7q/](http://jsfiddle.net/3e9d4v7q/)**

---

It's a moot point since you ***already*** have `required="required"` on those `input` elements, so you do not need to assign this rule again.  The jQuery Validate plugin will simply use any HTML5 attribute to assign the corresponding rule automatically.

**DEMO 2:  [jsfiddle.net/3e9d4v7q/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/3e9d4v7q/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

You could create your rules before you pass them into the validate function -

```
var rules = {};
$('input[name^=form]:text').each(function() {
    rules[this.name] = { required: true };
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#frmforgot").validate({
    rules: rules
  });
});
```

Comment: what if i have email field and required, email validation. Also in your answer "input[name^=form]" which is not in array format so i don't thinks it works

Comment: Why would it be in array format? rules is an object, even in your example. If you have additional requirements, please update the question.

Comment: `name` is as required in array format as per my requirement and i have also mention that `name` attribute is in array format. also my code display has same  'form[2][title]'. I think you don't have see the code